# CSVダウンロード時に、enumの表記を変更する方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Ruby on Railsでユーザーの名前等と、ステータスをダウンロードできるようにしようと考えています。
ステータスはenumで定義しており、現時点ではダウンロードするとenumのキーがそのまま表示されてしまいます。
このステータスをenumのキーに応じて日本語に変換し表示したいと考えてますが、ステータス列はenumで定義しているため別の値（日本語）を代入することができず、悩んでおります。

何か対応策がございましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いです。
下記、詳細となります。

---

## モデル

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :event, through: :target

  enum status: {default: nil, confirmed: 1, waiting: 2,canceled: 3}
end
```

---

## list_download.csv.ruby

```
require 'csv'
require 'nkf'

csv_str = CSV.generate do |csv|
  cols = {
    Target.human_attribute_name(:name)           => ->(s){ s.target.name },
    Applicant.human_attribute_name(:status)      => ->(s){ s.status },
    User.human_attribute_name(:user_name)        => ->(s){ s.user.user_name },
    User.human_attribute_name(:name)             => ->(s){ s.user.name },
    Applicant.human_attribute_name(:comment)     => ->(s){ s.comment },
  }

  # header の追加
  csv << cols.keys

  # body の追加
  @applicants.each do |applicant|
    #下記のように、日本語表記に変換したいと考えています。
    # case applicant.status
    # when "confirmed" then
    #   applicant.status = "参加確定"
    # when "waiting" then
    #   applicant.status = "キャンセル待ち"
    # when "canceled"
    #   applicant.status = "キャンセル"
    # end
    csv << cols.map{|k, col| col.call(applicant) }
  end
end
# 文字コード変換
NKF::nkf('--sjis -Lw', csv_str)
```

---

## list_download.csv

```
応募枠,参加可否,ユーザー名,名前,コメント
参加枠1,confirmed,aaa,佐藤たろう,参加します。
```

---

また下記のサイトを参考にさせていただきました。
[Rails で CSV ファイルを View を使って生成する](http://qiita.com/yutackall/items/24a4487f629a9106a971)

よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように`i18n`を利用してみてはいかがでしょうか？

### list_download.csv.ruby

```
require 'csv'

CSV.generate do |csv|
  cols = {
    Applicant.human_attribute_name(:status) => ->(s){ t("enums.applicant.status.#{s.status}") }
  }
  csv << cols.keys

  @applicants.each do |applicant|
    csv << cols.map{|k, col| col.call(applicant) }
  end
end
```

### ja.yml

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      applicant:
        status: ステータス
  enums:
    applicant:
      status:
        default: デフォルト
        confirmed: 確認済み
        waiting: 待機中
        canceled: キャンセル
```